# VS Code extension to correct html auto closing tag annoying behavior

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

1. I don't want VS code to generate the closing tag in HTML when i type then opening tag. For example, when i type `<p>`, i don't want a `</p>` to be added as i type. It's extremely annoying for me, so i deactivated the autoclosing tag setting.
2. And when i finish a content, and type `</`, i still want the corresponding tag to be automatically added.

Any ideas on how to obtain this "i don't type in advance, but i help you when you close" behavior, please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you turn off the `autoClosingTags` setting, Intellisense will suggest the closing tag for you when you type `</`, so just have to hit enter then. Without a custom VS Code extension, I don't think there is a setting for this out the box.

Answer (score 0):

Open VSCode, navigate to

> Preferences -> Settings

In the User Settings, click Text Editor, and look for the setting **Auto Closing Brackets**. Set it to never.

There is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) for the same also as u have asked in the question